# Ubercart add to cart trigger?

Tags: drupal, shopping-cart, ubercart

I want to keep track of all items added to uber cart. I.e. Whenever someone clicks ADD TO CART, I want to: create a database entry of the time and item added.

This way I can see which items are most clicked on.

The logic to add it to a db etc is easy to do. What I need to know is, how do I plug into the "add to cart" part. I.e. How do I know when this has been clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to implement [hook_add_to_cart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart) in a custom module, which will get called exactly as you describe above.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 it changed to hook_uc_add_to_cart